# Rails: Adding to errors[:base] does not make record invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `Purchase` model, I have a method that calculates the tax:

```
def calculate_tax
  if self.shipping_address.state == State.new_york
    corresponding_tax = Tax.find_by(zip_code: self.shipping_address.zip_code, state_id: self.shipping_address.state_id)
    if corresponding_tax
      self.tax = corresponding_tax.rate * (self.subtotal + shipping)
    else
      #HERE !!!
      self.errors[:base] << "The zip code you have entered is invalid."
      puts "errors = #{self.errors.full_messages}" #<-- this prints out the error in my log, so I know it's being run
    end
  else
    self.tax = 0.00
  end
end
```

This method is being called within this method:

```
def update_all_fees!
  calculate_subtotal
  calculate_shipping
  calculate_tax #<-- being called here
  calculate_total
  save!
end
```

However, `save!` is saving the record successfully. Shouldn't it be throwing an exception? How would I make it so that save! fails when calculate_tax is in the second `else` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add custom validation methods with the `validate` directive. Here's may take on the code you posted:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :new_york_needs_tax_record

  def update_all_fees!
    calculate_subtotal
    calculate_shipping
    calculate_tax
    calculate_total
    save!
  end

  private

  def calculate_tax
    if ships_to_new_york? && corresponding_tax
      self.tax = corresponding_tax.rate * (self.subtotal + shipping)
    elsif !ships_to_new_york?
      self.tax = 0.00
    else
      self.tax = nil
    end
  end

  def ships_to_new_york?
    self.shipping_address.state == State.new_york
  end

  def corresponding_tax
    Tax.find_by(zip_code: self.shipping_address.zip_code, state_id: self.shipping_address.state_id)
  end

  def new_york_need_tax_record
    if ships_to_new_york?  && !corresponding_tax
      self.errors[:base] << "The zip code you have entered is invalid."
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> Edited for historical reasons. The first response didn't cover all scenarios.

But if you need to raise the error if there are any just do:

```
validate :taxes_scenario

def taxes_scenario
  [Add any clause here that makes your scenario invalid]
end
```

So you can validate the taxes scenario and made sure your error is added properly.

Comment: This may not work well.  The valid? method clears out all errors and then runs it's validations setting new errors.  If called before your save your added error will have been "inadvertently" cleared. Have not checked if save calls valid? but I would bet that it does.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding an error to the error list won't make the record fail. You have to have what's called a "validation" set up. There are some wonderful guides about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) that should help you through the process.

For example in this one you will probably want to add to your Tax model the following validation:

`validates :zip_code, presence: true, numericality: true`

once you have the validations set up, `save!` should automatically spit out an error when a model fails validation

Comment: Validating the zip code won't help. I'm not validating on the Tax model, I'm trying to see if there's a matching tax record for a given zip code

Comment: Ah I see I see. Then @JorgedelosSantos's answer should be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 7:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  validate :must_be_a_friend

  def must_be_a_friend
    if friend == false
      # Does NOT work anymore
      errors[:base] << 'Must be friends'
    
      # DOES work
      errors.add(:base, 'Must be friends', strict: true)
    end
  end
  
end
```

Comment: This seems do not invalidate the model object i.e. do not mark as invalid the object.

Comment: It's because it should add `, strict: true` in the `add` method: `ruby
errors.add(:base, 'Must be friends', strict: true)`. 

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add

Comment: @Backo I have updated/corrected the answer.